# How to sniff/capture/trace USB data in recent macOS?

Tags: usb, kernel

The old 'USB Prober.app' does not work after Mavericks. Is there way to capture USB data in Sierra?

To be specific, I got a LG UltraFine 4K monitor, whose brightness can only be controlled from macOS via USB protocol

[image: USB brightness control LG UF 4K]

I would like to figure out the traffic data and write a utility for controlling brightness in other OSes.

The connection is a special DP over USB-C so I cannot use a hardward USB tracer.

Comment: Still have not got how do sniff USB in macOS.For my objective, I sniff the traffic when adjusting brightness using latest Boot Camp Support Software in Windows. Here is a standalone utility for adjusting brightness for this display without Boot Camp: https://github.com/unknownzerx/lguf-brightness/releases .

Comment: I would like to do the same... Did you ever succeed? I tried sniffing traffic using Wireshark on Windows, but there was no traffic on the USB port when modifying the room brightness. Otherwise, if you want to adjust the brightness manually, the link Fu Wenhui posted is a good solution. However, I was not successful building the tool on Linux. I was able to use a fork of that project on Windows though: https://github.com/csujedihy/LG-Ultrafine-Brightness